# Lenovo Ideapad laptop Updated BIOS - "Start PXE over IPv4" message (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, lenovo-laptop

I tried updating bios via the Lenovo BIOS Update Utility for my model. After flashing a new version it restarted into this message "Start PXE over IPv4". After a while it goes to a similiar one with IPv6 and then it opens Boot Menu. I googled a lot but couldn't find a solution for my exact problem. In most cases those users **COULD boot** into Windows just by rearranging the boot priority, but ***NOT ME***.

I have an SSD 128GB drive with my OS and a 1TB HDD. In BIOS I can see both drives, but when I try to boot from the SSD (or HDD, not sure what I was hoping for but still tried), it only goes to a same black screen and Start PXE message.

In BIOS I also noticed that the "Preinstalled OS license" says "NO DPK" but that could be due to this laptop not having a preinstalled OS when I bought it.

Not sure what more information should I provide. Using Windows 10 Pro.

Thanks!

Comment: if its a UEFI bios it won't recognize a non-UEFI OS installed. But since its Windows 10, I don't think non-UEFI even exists. But also, I think this would be more appropriate at SuperUser

Comment: The BIOS is set to UEFI mode yes, I can also set it to Legacy mode but that's it. Yeah sorry for that, I'm kinda new. I'll ask there. But still thanks very much!

Comment: @chiliNUT "since its Windows 10, I don't think non-UEFI even exists ....." - You would be incorrect.  Windows 10 supports both MBR and GPT.  MBR means Legacy Mode would be enabled aka Compatability Mode would be enabled aka CPM woudl be enabled and GPT means UEFI Mode aka all of those woudl be turned off.

Comment: @Hoverlord - Are you using GPT or MBR partitions?  Its very possible, by attempting to update the firmware, you wiped the keys required for UEFI mode.  If that's the case you would have to return the hardware to the manufacture for them to reload them.  You could format your drive and use MBR, more information is required, before I am prepared to say thats your answer to your problem though.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't know there was an MBR version of windows 10. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all so much for your replies. I managed to make a bootable usb drive so I could look at the SSD closely and I found out, that the system was there (At first I got scared that somehow, my ssd got formatted, but this was kinda relief), so I went to the BIOS again and switched UEFI to **Legacy Mode** (and also turned the Secure Boot off - dunno Why I did that, somebody somewhere posted that it could help as well). This solved the problem as it boots normally ever since.

Comment: Secure Boot only works with UEFI booting anyway.